# Filter for top 3 values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {1: {'shooting': 9,
  'photography': 43,
  'portrait': 17,
  'portraitphotography': 4,
  'model': 40,
  'modeling': 10,
  'lovemyjob': 13,
  'buzzcut': 86}
2: {'lowbun': 18,
  'sleekhair': 4,
  'girl': 94,
  'profile': 4,
  'lips': 31,
  'choker': 16,
  'gold': 16,
  'minimalist': 1}
3: {'chaching': 1,
  'newhair': 20,
  'happy': 31,
  'besthairdresser': 2,
  'hairdresser': 85,
  'treatyoself': 1,
  'loveit': 12,
  'brunette': 36,
  'foils': 325}
```

I want to get the top 3 values within each dictionary so it should look something like this:

```
{1: {'buzzcut': 86
  'photography': 43,
  'model': 40}
2: {'girl': 94,
  'lips': 31,
  'lowbun': 18}
3: {'foils': 325
  'hairdresser': 85,
  'brunette': 36}
```

I've tried using
`mydict = dict(sorted(mydict.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:3])`
but I get the error `not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to loop on the outer dicts too. Your current code would work on a single inner dict.

Comment: A remotely related remark: you should be using dict when you don't care about the order, i.e. when you access items by name. If you are interested in what are the "top 3 values", you should be using a list instead.

Comment: @zvone You could use a dict and care about the order, that's what `OrderedDict`s are for.

Comment: Both the dict you claim to have and the dict you desire have several syntax errors. Not exactly helpful.

Comment: @Algebra8 Just because you can use it, does not mean it is the best choice. It is completely unclear why the OP would want the "top 3 values", but they apparently don't care about the dict keys, so there is no reason to have a dict at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with simple dictionary comprehension:

```
q = {
    j: dict(sorted(
        mydict[j].items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)[:3]) 
    for j in mydict
}
```

Result:

```
>>> print(q)
{1: {'buzzcut': 86, 'photography': 43, 'model': 40}, 2: {'girl': 94, 'lips': 31, 'lowbun': 18}, 3: {'foils': 325, 'hairdresser': 85, 'brunette': 36}}
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention - I'll update my answer.

Comment: That's interesting, I just realized `pprint` would mess up the order of my results...

Comment: You can still use `pprint`, just with argument `sort_dicts=False`. Or use `pp`, where that's the default.

Comment: I'll remember that for next time

Comment: Valuable that I do not have to import any library to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and efficient one using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> {k: dict(Counter(mydict[k]).most_common(3)) for k in mydict}
{1: {'buzzcut': 86, 'photography': 43, 'model': 40},
 2: {'girl': 94, 'lips': 31, 'lowbun': 18},
 3: {'foils': 325, 'hairdresser': 85, 'brunette': 36}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort dictionaries by value using sorted(), it will return you a sorted list of tuples containing first the key and second the value of the key

```
sorted_values_1 = sorted(mydict[1].items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
#In this example it will return:
#[('buzzcut', 86), ('photography', 43), ('model', 40), ('portrait', 17), ('lovemyjob', 13), ('modeling', 10), ('shooting', 9), ('portraitphotography', 4)]
```

Put first 3 in a dictionary and you are done

```
counter = 0
top_3_1 = {}
for i in sorted_values_1:
    top_3_1[i[0]] = i[1]
    counter += 1
    if counter == 3:
        break

print(top_3_1)
#Output: {'buzzcut': 86, 'photography': 43, 'model': 40}
```